# Need to change class in CSS for a DIV based on different screen sizes

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, responsive-design

**Need to change class in CSS for a DIV based on different screen sizes**

```
<div id="tab" class="tab_small"></div>
```

I need to change class of DIV having ID "tab" to "tab_small","tab_medium" & "tab_large"
based on the screen size using css only

```
@media(max-width:450px){tab_small class will apply} 
@media(min-width:450px) and (max-width:768px){tab_medium will apply}
@media(min-width:768px) and (max-width:990px){tab_large will apply}
```

Is that doable?

with JS I can do, Is there a way to do with CSS in bootstrap?

**If all three classes will be there in HTML on that DIV, is there a way to display one out of them in html based on screen sizes?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `@media all and (max-width: 768px) { .className { property: value; } }`

Comment: No, css cannot change the source of a html page, only how it renders. So, you cannot change the class, but you can change how the element displays.

Comment: If all three classes will be there in HTML on that DIV, is there a way to activate one out of them based on screen sizes?

Comment: You don't need to apply different classes. Just change the CSS for the one class within each media query.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your valuable suggestions, I guess sushil has described the right context. I got it.

Comment: I am amazed at how many upvotes the answers to this question got, even though 2 of them didn't answer the question, and the accepted one stated exactly what I said at the beginning >.<

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not way to change DOM property value using CSS. There is only way to achieve this using javascript.

Comment: This is what I was asking, is there a possibility or not to change the DOM property in any way using CSS.. JS can do it...  But I was wondering if similar can be achieved by disabling or removing classes based on screen sizes, @sushil: I guess you picked up the right context, Thanks

Comment: Right @CreativePS, we can override the css properties using media queries but can't change the DOM properties using CSS.

Comment: hey @Jay: you seems to be a very conservative professional. I know media queries and all very well, Its just that sometimes there are great possibilities that we may not know.. I think this platform is to explore those possibilities..

Comment: it was just a question to know if anyone know beyond what is traditional.. please don't take any thing personal here.. people are here to learn more & not only to share what they already know

Comment: @CreativePS Sorry. I'm not trying to be rude or a pain. But there is absolutely no benefit in doing what you're trying to achieve if you're basing it upon screen size.

Comment: Its ok jay..that I did using js my brother, its just that I asked this question because I thought may be 1% there may be some sought of solution through CSS because it was related to different screen sizes. anyways.. I appreciate everyone here who spare time to solve other's people problems

Answer (score 4):

I think you are trying to achieve a behavior like this. Try to resize the fiddle window. Please be aware that setting a property within `#tab` selector will override the `@media` queries, if you want to prevent this behavior just use `#tab .tab_small`, `#tab .tab_medium`, `#tab .tab_large` selectors inside the `@media` queries.

```
#tab{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
@media(max-width:450px){
    .tab_small{
       background:red;
    }
} 
@media(min-width:450px) and (max-width:768px){
    .tab_medium{
       background: green;
    }
}
@media(min-width:768px) and (max-width:990px){
    .tab_large{
       background: blue;
    }
}
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bkq874f6/)**

Comment: What's the point in having all those classes attached if you're just going to change the CSS applied with a media query.

Comment: Thanks, but I guess sushil has picked the right context of the question. thumbs up for your efforts :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this jQuery js solution, probably this will resolve your issue..

```
<div id="tab" class=""></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
if($('body').width() < 450){
    $('#tab').addClass('tab_small');
}else if($('body').width() > 450 && $('body').width() < 768){
   $('#tab').addClass('tab_medium');
}else{
    $('#tab').addClass('tab_large');
}
</script>
```